# What is the purpose of warning areas?

Tags: pilots, airspace, student-pilot

What purpose does the warning area serve?
Is it like CFA'S, MOA'S?

Comment: Could you provide a little more detail, what is an example of a warning area you're asking about? What specifically do you want to know? What juristiction are you asking about?

Comment: Have you looked up the definition?  The purpose is often embedded in the definition.  (I.e. “international airspace with a high volume of military training…”

Comment: I had the definition but I wanted more of a vivid picture on what happens in that airspace.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

AIM 3-4-4 states.

> A warning area is airspace of defined dimensions, extending from three nautical miles outward from the coast of the U.S., that contains activity that may be hazardous to nonparticipating aircraft. The purpose of such warning areas is to warn nonparticipating pilots of the potential danger. A warning area may be located over domestic or international waters or both.

These areas have typically been used for hazardous activities e.g. supersonic flight by military aircraft, live firing of guided missiles (W-151 areas off the coast of Tyndal AFB), aerial warfare exercises, etc.

A chief difference between Warning and Restricted or Prohibited areas is that most Warning areas lie off the coast in international waters where the US does not have the ability to exercise control of this airspace or prohibit entrance under international law.  IFR traffic is routed around by ATC from these areas but there are no restrictions for VFR traffic entering Warning areas.  These The areas function sort of a courtesy call to both civil and military air traffic operating in international waters that the US conduct these kinds of hazardous activities within.

Comment: A key difference between Warning areas and Restricted areas are that the Warning areas are mostly in international airspace (over international waters) where no state is allowed to restrict access according to ICAO agreements. Operationally, ATC won't route any traffic through a Warning area, but they can't stop VFR traffic from entering (they will advise to avoid an active Warning area.) The areas off Eglin AFB are active most weekdays.